# String split returns null pointer exception

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to remove `".txt"` extension from my file name yet I'm getting a `NullPointerException` on line 2.

Filename equals `"myfilename.txt"` and It's a string, I'd tried printing it

```
String token[]=fileName.split(".");
File JSONFile = new File(rootFile.getPath()+"\\"+token[0]+ ".json");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` is a special character so you need to escape it with backslash `\\`

Try this:

```
String token[] = fileName.split("\\.");
File JSONFile = new File(rootFile.getPath()+"\\"+token[0]+ ".json");
```